# Cannot Load Such File -- sqlite3 Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, rake-task

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- sqlite3
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/tools.rb:343:in `require'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/backports-3.6.0/lib/backports/tools.rb:343:in `require_with_backports'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `block in require'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:9:in `block in require_library_or_gem'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `block in silence_warnings'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:22:in `with_warnings'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:7:in `require_library_or_gem'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:24:in `sqlite3_connection'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `new_connection'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:237:in `checkout_new_connection'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:191:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `loop'
/var/www/BookBuilder/releases/20140317160018/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.0.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:187:in `block in checkout'
```

I'm running the rake task on the staging server, which is using postgresql for the database, and for some reason I'm getting an error for sqlite3 which is used only for development. Please provide some insight on this issue

Database:

```
development:
 adapter: sqlite3
 database: db/development.sqlite3
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000

test: &test
 adapter: sqlite3
 database: db/test.sqlite3
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000

staging:
 encoding: unicode
 adapter: postgresql
 username: postgres
 port: 5432
 host: localhost
 database: staging
 password: password
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.12'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7'

gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'airbrake'

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'paperclip-meta'
gem 'spree', '0.60.6'
gem 'simple_xlsx_writer'
gem 'rubyzip',  "~> 0.9.9"
gem 'resque', :require => 'resque/server'
gem 'pdfkit', '0.5.2'
gem 'imgkit', '1.3.7'
gem 'pony'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :staging do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :production do
  gem 'mysql'
end

gem 'net-ssh', '2.7.0'
gem 'capistrano'

gem 'will_paginate_renderers', '0.0.3'

gem "httparty", "~> 0.7.8"

gem "spree_theme", :path => "spree_theme", :require => "spree_theme"
gem "spree_customizations", :path => "spree_customizations", :require => "spree_customizations"

gem "yell-rails", "1.4.0"
gem "yell-adapters-gelf"
```

Comment: Please, add your database configuration and your Gemfile.

Comment: ok, i added db config and gemfile

Comment: Are you running the rake task setting the correct rails env? 

    RAILS_ENV=staging rake ....

Comment: Rails_env=staging bundle exec rake task_name --trace. that is my command

Answer (score 0):

I would personally try this:

```
bundle install --without production
rake task_name RAILS_ENV=staging
```